# Build issues with cardslib using eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, cardslib

I am a newbie in android dev and using Eclipse for now. I am trying to use Cardslib library but even after following the mentioned steps, I am unable to build the library successfully.

Specifically after the following step:
 - mark java(*) folder as source (click on folder -> Build-Path -> use as source folder). You can also remove the src folder, from the project.

I get the error in the java folder such as:

```
[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] /Users/shrtrive/Documents/cardslib/cardslib-master/library-cards/src/cardslib/res/values/styles.xml:34: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native.content_outer_layout'.

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib]

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] /Users/shrtrive/Documents/cardslib/cardslib-master/library-cards/src/cardslib/res/values/styles.xml:48: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] 

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] /Users/shrtrive/Documents/cardslib/cardslib-master/library-cards/src/cardslib/res/values/styles.xml:55: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] 

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib] /Users/shrtrive/Documents/cardslib/cardslib-master/library-cards/src/cardslib/res/values/styles.xml:64: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'card.native'.

[2015-09-08 09:53:57 - cardslib]
```

As per the manifest the minSdkversion is 14 and target is 21.

Comment: did u added jar or source code as lib?

Comment: ok so u added source code  as lib?

Comment: @N5. Well yes I am trying to add source code as library. I followed the steps as mentioned here : https://github.com/gabrielemariotti/cardslib/blob/master/doc/BUILD.md#reference-this-project-as-a-library-in-eclipse.

Comment: so is the libs and ur code in same workspace?

Comment: @N5. Yes they are in the same workspace.

Comment: IN which module do you have the error? Cardslib has different modules now.